# Error Nginx 499 (client close connection) with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nginx

I have a problem during the production of my site. I am trying to send a POST request to Node.js but it returns the error `499`.

- nginx
- nodejs (express package)
- no php

Nginx Configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name *********.com;

    access_log /var/www/*********/log/access.log main;
    error_log /var/www/*********/log/error.log;

    root /var/www/*********.com/www;
    index index.html;

    if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' ) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /admin/articles {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
    }
}
```

Complete Nginx configuration & permissions (755 directories / 644 files) :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}

Form HTML :

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/articles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row row-sm-offset">
    <div class="col-md-12" data-for="pageName">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label mbr-   fonts-style display-7" for="pageName-form1-ti">Nom de la page (ex : index.html)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pageName" data-form-field="pageName" required="" id="pageName-form1-ti">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" data-for="pageTitle">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="pageTitle-form1-ti">Titre de la page (ex : Acceuil)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pageTitle" data-form-field="pageTitle" required="" id="pageTitle-form1-ti">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12" data-for="pageDescription">
      <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="pageDescription-form1-ti">Description de la page (SEO)</label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="pageDescription" rows="7" data-form-field="pageDescription" id="pageDescription-form1-ti"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 multi-horizontal" data-for="pageDate">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="pageDate-form1-ti">Date de publication (ex : 17/10/19)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pageDate" data-form-field="pageDate" id="pageDate-form1-ti">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 multi-horizontal" data-for="pageImg">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="pageImg-form1-ti">Imagette de l'article (ex: image.jpg)</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="pageImg" data-form-field="pageImg" id="pageImg-form1-ti">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="submit-form" href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form display-4">Ajouter l'article</button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Script Node.js :

```
app.post('/admin/articles', function(request,response) {
    console.log("Route : app.post /admin/articles");

    var params = {
        pageName        : request.body.pageName,
        pageTitle       : request.body.pageTitle,
        pageDescription : request.body.pageDescription,
        pageDate        : request.body.pageDate,
        pageImg         : request.body.pageImg
    };

    postManager.getLastIndex();
    postManager.writePost(params);

});
```

Access logs :

```
"POST /admin/articles HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "https://**********.com/admin/admin.html?pageName=test.html&pageTitle=Module+de+test&pageDescription=dfsdfsdfsf&pageDate=11%2F10%2F1995&pageImg="
```

I tried everything! I do not know where the error is. Probably a problem in the Nginx configuration.

If you have ideas, do not hesitate to share!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to try increasing the client timeout as a start.

Comment: 149/5000
@AHT - Already done .. I always fall back on the same mistake.

My script is not long normally, it will just open and write to an empty .txt file ..

Comment: Can you provide the complete nginx configuration you have and the permissions for your nginx directory?

Comment: @AHT - added in the post